# Where can I find the source code for Android's stock launcher gallery widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

I'm looking for the source code of this infinite/looping widget that Android uses for its Photo Gallery and Google Play Books home/launcher widget; can you help me find it?

Thanks

[image: Launcher Photo Gallery Widget]

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will find something interesting here: [android.widget.Gallery](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/widget/Gallery.java?av=f)
But, I don't know if this widget is the same that you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah, that's just the Android UI element Gallery and the first line of comment says "A view that shows items in a center-locked, horizontally scrolling list". Thanks though.